# Identifying source of parser errors in Apache Fuseki

Tags: jena, fuseki

I am getting the following error in trying to load a large RDF/XML document into Fuseki:

```
> Code: 4/UNWISE_CHARACTER in PATH: The character matches no grammar rules of URIs/IRIs. These characters are permitted in RDF URI References, XML system identifiers, and XML Schema anyURIs.
```

How do I find out what line contains the offending error?

I have tried turning up the output in Log4j.properties and I also tried validating the RDF/XML file using the Jena commandline rdfxml tool (as well as utf8 & riot) --- it validates with no errors reported.  But I'm new to this toolset.

Answer (score 0):

(version?)

Check the ""-strings in your RDF/XML data for undesiravle URIs - especially spaces in URIs.

Best to validate before loading : try `riot YourFile` and send stderr and stdout to a file.  The errors should be approximately in the position of the parser output (N-triples) at the time.

Comment: Now I do see the problem -- the path it was objecting to was actually the path to the RDF file -- I specified a UNC path, and apparently UNC paths aren't supported.